# Export Infopath Data into Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, sharepoint-server

In one of my doucment library there are more then 100 infopath forms holding customers data.And we are mvoing all the infopath data into SharePoint list .Can any one help me how can I move the infopath data into SharePoint list or Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 0):

**To export InfoPath data to Excel** [Export form data to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Export-form-data-to-Excel-7539dee7-9268-4f2e-9361-802138bc9685)

**To export InfoPath data to a list** would require a custom feature or a third party tool like [Qdabra](http://formsquo.com/15578/free-tool-to-migrate-infopath-data-into-sharepoint-lists/#!prettyPhoto) This tool works even with 2007 version which is currently your requirement.

I had came across one detailed article on [How Do I Map InfoPath Form Data to a SharePoint List?](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-do-i-map-infopath-form-data-to-a-sharepoint-list)

This article may help you in some or other way but the efficient approach would be using Qdabra tool to export InfoPath data to a list.